# How to create SubOjectProperty from ObjectProperty for Association case?

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

I am developing an algorithm using OWL API with Java (Eclipse). For my ASSOCIATION case, I need to create an axiom with AGGREGATION and COMPOSITION as SubObjectProperty from ASSOCIATION object. However from my code I keep on prompted to change the ASSOCIATION object to class in which I did not prefer to. How can I fix this?

I have tried using OWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom to create the axiom but prompted to cast argument ASSOCIATION to OWLClassExpression (I did not prefer this).

```
OWLObjectProperty ASSOCIATION = df.getOWLObjectProperty(IOR + "/ASSOCIATION");
OWLObjectProperty AGGREGATION = df.getOWLObjectProperty(IOR + "/AGGREGATION");
OWLObjectProperty COMPOSITION = df.getOWLObjectProperty(IOR + "/COMPOSITION");
OWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom axAssociation = df.getOWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom
(
df.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(AGGREGATION, ASSOCIATION),
df.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(COMPOSITION, ASSOCIATION)
);

I am expecting to be able to create an axiom for AGGREGATION to be a SubObjectProperty from ASSOCIATION object.
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You have 3 object properties and now? The subproperty axiom needs 2 object properties. Don't know why you use 2 someValuesFrom restrictions which in fact are class expressions. If you want to say that `AGGREGATION` is a subproperty of `ASSOCIATION`, then do `df.getOWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom
(AGGREGATION, ASSOCIATION)` and obviously you have to create a second axiom for the other case. You should also make use of Javadoc and maybe read again about the axioms in the OWL 2 W3C docs.

Comment: This help thank you very much. I am relatively new to this.

Comment: ok, no problem - but it might help if you walk through an OWL 2 tutorial or just the W3C docs. At least you should understand what `ObjectSomeValuesFrom` and all the other stuff means - it's not that difficult, you just have to read about all the OWL constructs once and you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

> but prompted to cast argument ASSOCIATION to OWLClassExpression

That is incorrect. The argument type is `OWLObjectPropertyExpression` and it must accept arguments typed as `OWLObjectProperty`.

If this does not help solve your problem, please post the full class, including import statements, and the OWLAPI version you're using so the situation can be replicated.

Comment: Thank you. I manage to get the desired output by using df.getOWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom (AGGREGATION, ASSOCIATION).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I manage to get the desired output by using df.getOWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom (AGGREGATION, ASSOCIATION) as suggested.